# Nodes.js installation on ec2 : no symlink created

Tags: node.js

I have some problems to launch node and npm after compiling them from source.
I have installed node on an AWS ec2, a micro instance, with a Virtualmin AMI based on RedHat.
Since it’s a micro instance, it took nearly 2 hours to compile ...

Here is how I installed it :

```
wget -N http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-latest.tar.gz
cd node-latest
make
make install
```

After that, typing `node -v` did nothing. `command not found`.
Nothing for `npm -v` too.

Im not very comfortable with Linux but I understand that no symlink have been created for node and npm. Aren’t they supposed to be created automatically ?

For node I can do :

```
ln -s /usr/local/src/node-v0.10.5/out/Release/node /usr/bin/node
```

And then `node -v` gives me what I expected : `v0.10.5`

Then I am doing the same for npm

```
ln -s /usr/local/src/node-v0.10.5/deps/npm/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

But trying `npm -v` doesn’t work as good :

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

It seems thats it is searching for some files in the `/usr/bin/` directory, but those files are in the `/usr/local/src/node-v0.10.5/deps/npm/` directory.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This is much better suited to [Serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: What's your `PATH`? (`echo $PATH`)

Comment: `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node-waf /usr/bin/node-waf
```

But it definitely should not take 2 hours! I launch EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS instance with node through CloudInit and UserData in several minutes.

You can this script instead:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
apt-get update
apt-get install -y nodejs
npm install npm -g
```

Comment: I have nothing to symlink from `/usr/local/bin`  The directory is empty  It took 2 hours because it is a micro instance and compiling from source uses a lot of CPU, and CPU is capped on micro instance http://john.krasnay.ca/2012/01/31/ec2-micro-instance-throttling.html

Comment: The Virtualmin AMI is based on RedHat, it uses YUM, not APT :(